Whenever I try to install global npm packages, I get permission denied. How can I solve this. How can I install without using sudo first
when i try to install ex:
npm install -g n
I got a error:
npm error code EACCES
npm error syscall rename
npm error path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/n 
npm error dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.n-oBR4I52F 
npm error errno -13 
npm error Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/n' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.n-oBR4I52F' 
npm error     at async Object.rename (node:internal/fs/promises:782:10)
npm error     at async moveFile (/usr/lib64/node_modules/npm20/node_modules/@npmcli/fs/lib/move-file.js:30:5)
npm error     at async Promise.allSettled (index 0) 
npm error     at async [reifyPackages] (/usr/lib64/node_modules/npm20/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:325:11) 
npm error     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/lib64/node_modules/npm20/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:142:5) 
npm error     at async Install.exec (/usr/lib64/node_modules/npm20/lib/commands/install.js:150:5) 
npm error     at async module.exports (/usr/lib64/node_modules/npm20/lib/cli/entry.js:74:5) { 
npm error   errno: -13, 
npm error   code: 'EACCES', 
npm error   syscall: 'rename', 
npm error   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/n', 
npm error   dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.n-oBR4I52F' 
npm error } 
npm error 

i try to install with sudo, but do not work. my company is blocking the installation.

Based on your log errors, i can see that is EACCES permissions errors
As the npm package documentation suggest, try to manually npm default directory, you can follow the steps mentioned in this document:

Note: Below links works in Mac and Linux based OS, not for Windows.


Manually change npm's default directory
Resolving EACCES permissions errors

So even if you do not get your issue resolved after changing directory manually, taking a look at these source should help you out:

Error: EACCES, permission denied even after using sudo?
Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'

Hope these will help you fix installing the packages globally.
